# Check if FileStream is from a ZipArchive

Tags: c#, filestream, c#-ziparchive

If I have a FileStream how can I check if it's from a ZipArchive ?
Now I use a try catch statement that throw a

*'System.IO.InvalidDataException: 'End of Central Directory record could not be found.'*

if the stream is not from a ZipArchive.

```
try
{
    ZipArchive za = new ZipArchive(fIleStream, ZipArchiveMode.Read);
    ...
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . Why do you need to do this?

Comment: If you are not comfortable with zip specification - I'd use current method and allow ZipArchive figure it out for you. Of course ideally you should know by external means (such as file extension) if file is exptected to be zip or not.

Comment: I have a function that accept a string (file name) or a Stream as parameter. If I have a Stream I want to know if it's from a ZipArchive.

Answer (score 3):

You could sniff the first two bytes of the stream to see if it matches the zip signature.

As described here
https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT

Should be 0x504b to be zip data.

Comment: It's 50 4B, not 4B 50. And anyway, in theory it's not enough to detect zip file. That is - there are valid zip files which do not start with 50 4B.